# Infinite loop, if non existing endpoint or endpoint without url param ir called

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have encountered a problem, that, if I call an endpoint from Postman, that does not exist in my API, in the console I can see, that it is going into an infinite loop. The loop continues, until I stop the API manually.
For example- I have an endpoint GET /api/v1/contoller/count/{timestamp}. If I do not specify the timestamp, and send the request to /api/v1/controller/count/ or /api/v1/controller/count , then the request is getting looped, until I disable the API. The same is happening, if I call just the route to the controller (/api/v1/controller).

The Startup.cs file is configured like this:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment currentEnvironment;

    private IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment currentEnvironment)
    {
        this.currentEnvironment = currentEnvironment;
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc(opts => { opts.ValueProviderFactories.Add(new ValueFromClaimProviderFactory()); })
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
            

        services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore;
            options.SerializerSettings.DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
        });

        services.AddAppSettings(Configuration);
        services.AddAutoMapper();
        services.AddConnectionProvider(Configuration);
        services.AddMediatR(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(AutofacModule)));
        services.AddSwagger();
        services.AddJwt(Configuration);

        if (currentEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            services.AddSpa();
        }

        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddFormFileFileSizeLimit();

        return services.AddAutofac(Configuration);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.Use(next => context => { context.Request.EnableBuffering(); return next(context); });
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });

        var appSettings = Configuration.Get<AppSettings>();
        if (appSettings.MigrateOnStartup)
        {
            app.MigrateDatabase();
        }

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSpa(env);
            return;
        }

        app.SetDefaultFileSavePath();
    }
}
```

Request spam looks like this in the console:

```
[23:46:53 INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:4200/api/v1/controller - -
[23:46:53 INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:4200/api/v1/controller - -
[23:46:53 INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:4200/api/v1/controller - -
[23:46:53 INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:4200/api/v1/controller - -
[23:46:53 INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:4200/api/v1/controller - -
[23:46:53 INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:4200/api/v1/controller - -
[23:46:53 INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:4200/api/v1/controller - -
[23:46:53 INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/api/v1/controller - -
[23:46:53 INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:4200/api/v1/controller - -
[23:46:53 INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:4200/api/v1/controller - -
[23:46:53 INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:4200/api/v1/controller - -
[23:46:53 INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:4200/api/v1/controller - -
[23:46:53 INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/api/v1/controller - -
[23:46:53 INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:4200/api/v1/controller - -
[23:46:53 INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:4200/api/v1/controller - -
[23:46:53 INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:4200/api/v1/controller - -
[23:46:53 INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:4200/api/v1/controller - -
[23:46:53 INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:4200/api/v1/controller - -
```

If I stop the API, then it prints out 200 OK for every request it initiated

```
[23:50:33 INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:4200/api/v1/controller - - - 200 0 - 1919.1311ms
[23:50:33 INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:4200/api/v1/controller - - - 200 0 - 2054.1207ms
[23:50:33 INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:4200/api/v1/controller - - - 200 0 - 2289.0213ms
[23:50:33 INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:4200/api/v1/controller - - - 200 0 - 2006.3594ms
[23:50:33 INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:4200/api/v1/controller - - - 200 0 - 2352.4241ms
[23:50:33 INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:4200/api/v1/controller - - - 200 0 - 2400.1864ms
[23:50:33 INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:4200/api/v1/controller - - - 200 0 - 2416.0991ms
[23:50:33 INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:4200/api/v1/controller - - - 200 0 - 2435.2875ms
[23:50:33 INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/api/v1/controller - - - 200 0 - 2647.8172ms
[23:50:33 INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:4200/api/v1/controller - - - 200 0 - 1597.2806ms
[23:50:33 INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:4200/api/v1/controller - - - 200 0 - 1551.9350ms
[23:50:33 INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:4200/api/v1/controller - - - 200 0 - 1149.6773ms
[23:50:33 INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:4200/api/v1/controller - - - 200 0 - 1053.8900ms
[23:50:33 INF] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:4200/api/v1/controller - - - 200 0 - 1398.5423ms
```

If I let to run this loop for long enough, I get an Internal Server Error:

> Error occurred while trying to proxy: localhost:4200/api/v1/controller

Also, I noticed, that it is trying to contact the API on port 4200, and sometimes on port 5000. 5000 is the port on which my API is served locally, and 4200 ir the port on which I serve Angular project for frontend.

Does anyone know, what could be the problem here?